# Using Mongoose query outside exec function

Tags: express, mongoose, exec

I am trying to use the result of a query outside the exec function, but I can't seem to get it working

This is my function in Express

```
getUrlsFromDatabase = function(){
  blog.find()
  .select('url')
  .exec(function(err,docs){
    var sitemap = [];
    for(var i=0; i<docs.length; i++) {
      sitemap.push(docs[i].url);
    }
    return sitemap
  })
  console.log("Trying to get result docs here")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using async/await

```js
getUrlsFromDatabase = async function(){

  var blogs = await blog.find().select('url')

  var sitemap = [];

  for(var i=0; i<docs.length; i++) {
    sitemap.push(docs[i].url);
  }

  return sitemap 

  console.log("Trying to get result docs here")
}
```

Update:

Or just add a return to back some result from the function

```js
getUrlsFromDatabase = function(){
 return blog.find() // <- add return here
  .select('url')
  .exec(function(err,docs){
    var sitemap = [];
    for(var i=0; i<docs.length; i++) {
      sitemap.push(docs[i].url);
    }
    return sitemap
  })
  console.log("Trying to get result docs here")
}
```

Or just save It in a variable:

```js
getUrlsFromDatabase = function(){
 const result = blog.find() // <- add variable here
  .select('url')
  .exec(function(err,docs){
    var sitemap = [];
    for(var i=0; i<docs.length; i++) {
      sitemap.push(docs[i].url);
    }
    return sitemap
  })
  return result // to return it outbound
}
```